# windows 7 freezes on boot but not on restart

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze

I have a strange issue with Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. When I press the button to start the PC, shows all messages, pass the Windows loading screen and stuck before the welcome screen. It shows a black screen (no messages) and nothing is possible. Keyboard and mouse are not working and cursor is not visible.
When I press the restart button, all are fine. Windows login correctly.

What I tried:

- scan the machine with updated version of free edition of AVG.
- scan the machine with the latest version of CCleaner and clear
  anything it found (files, registry etc).
- read about the black screen of death (I am not sure this is applied
  in my situation) and downloaded a fix but the issue remains.
- to fix the startup with windows disk (it didn't find any
  error).
- search google for similar issues, without success

Any ideas?

Comment: I have a good answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/559923/windows-7-is-stuck-at-starting-windows-when-i-attempt-to-boot-computer/560105#560105

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

BIOS! (Really nasty stuff can affect your BIOS. Did you "flash" it for some reason or not protect it from flashing?)

Failing CPU. Is the CPU too hot? Or was it?! Too many dust bunnies on the heat sink? Is the heat sink even on?!!! (I've seen that a couple of times.) Could the RAM use a re seating? (Highly unlikely, but it's still just too quick and easy to not try it.)

Failing hard drive. Got any bad sectors? Has the SMART flag been tripped? Done a disk check to see?! (Probably have to schedule one or use a rescue/boot disk to run it.)

Has some utility like MSCONFIG been used and now there are changes? You can also flub stuff up like that with CCleaner too. Although with CCleaner, just check your startup items and make sure all things are enabled before uninstalling or changing things.

Checked your hidden boot partition (usually called "System Reserved") for problems? Do you even have a separate boot partition?! (It is possible to install Windows on one partition but that's not the default way of doing it.)

I have other ideas. but I'd probably start off with a good case cleaning and re seating of all things from cables to expansion cards to CPU and even RAM. You might even want to try a better power supply if you have one too (at the very least, use a surge suppressor in case you're in an area with bad "dirty" power).

Probably not much help. But those are a few ideas...

Comment: FYI: MSCONFIG is the "great glue" that is about to go main stream in Windows 8. But make no mistake! MSCONFIG was originally designed as a tool and not intended to be used as a permanent fix. Look hard enough and even Microsoft once said this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get to the login screen, you could try

After you get the blank screen, ( After logging in. )
Press either Ctrl+Shift+Esc, or Ctrl+Alt+Delete.
Once you do that, the task manager should open up.
Once open, go to processes and look for Explorer.exe, You might not find it, Because sometimes apparently Vista forgets to start it.
If it is there, Right click it, and End Process.
Once done, ( Follow this step if it isnt there also. )
Go to the Applications tab, and click 'New Task...'
Type in Explorer.exe
This should force the GUI to load, and you shouldnt have any problems from there...
If your computer is new, I'd suggest getting the new Drivers also, as this may reduce the number of times you'll have to do this.
(from http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-6-windows-black-screen)

Comment: as I wrote keyboard and mouse not working

Comment: Try this (although the actual answer is on page 2, I suggest reading it all) - there is too much to copy onto superuser website: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/windows-wont-boot-first-time-but-after-hard-reset/424688bf-a83c-483b-9a1d-de8393547142

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't fix errors with **any** registry cleaners...

*Follow this procedure step by step*

1. Check the graphic card driver by reinitializing or updating it

   Start Task Manager, kill explorer.exe, start a new task:
   explorer.exe, run `devmgmt.msc` as administrator, check the graphic
   card properties, update the driver from Internet. Restart the PC.
2. Check for error in the registry

   Start Task Manager, kill explorer.exe, start a new task:
   explorer.exe,start `regedit.exe` as administrator:

   go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
   NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

   the value of **Shell** must be **explorer.exe** if not change it.
   Restart the PC.
3. At boot press the F8 key and go in safe mode and choose in the
   advanced option:

   *Last known good configuration*
4. At boot press the F8 key and go in safe mode and choose in the
   advanced option:

   *System Restore option*

   You may also check these MSKB articles

[How to troubleshoot a problem by performing a clean boot in Windows Vista or in Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)

[Uninstalling the video driver on a computer running Windows 7 may result in a black screen](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2425157)

Hope this help. Let us know.