# Windows 8 stuck on login screen after restart

Tags: windows, windows-8

My PC heats up a lot and automatically switches off. Recently when it turned off automatically, I restarted my Windows and it got stuck on login screen for about `15 mins` and now it happens on every restart. After entering the password too, it gets stuck for around `10 mins`.

I tried `defragmenting`, `virus scan`, using `cCleaner` to clean temp files and registry and installing different antivirus. The system restore points are also corrupted. What could be the problem? I am using Windows 8.

Comment: All other things? Make it clear please so we don't have to write out what you already did!

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is that your "PC heats up a lot and automatically switches off". If the heat is what's causing the shutdowns, and it's been happening a lot, then it's likely that you've damaged a component or two. A PC that's hot enough to complain by shutting down is never a good thing.

I would suggest checking the cooling of your PC components before trying anything else.  Most PC BIOS' will have a method of checking the temperature of your devices, so it would be worth checking there after an automatic shutdown.

---

As anecdotal evidence, a colleagues laptop kept overheating, and he now has a dead hard drive with no way of getting to the data - collecting [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) data from the drive, via the drive manufacturers diagnostic tools, showed a large number of errors due to high temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have damaged some of system files or settings.
If its not corrupted-hardware problem then it's probably fault of registry.
1) Try to recover from Backup.
2) Try to boot with Safe Mode. Does it work normally?
3) If nothing helped, there's a good way to recover from all that registry-problems without reinstalling OS, and I've explained it **[HERE](https://superuser.com/a/560105/180465)**.

Comment: So why didn't you link directly to your own answer instead of linking to someone else's?