# Windows 7 being installed on my new HDD, but not working

Tags: windows-7

I saw your answer to a question and wanted to ask for your advise since you seem to know what you are talking about. Here is the link to the article I found your answer on:

[Windows 7 is stuck at "Starting Windows" when I attempt to boot computer](https://superuser.com/questions/559923/windows-7-is-stuck-at-starting-windows-when-i-attempt-to-boot-computer)

Me and a friend were installing Windows 7 on my new computer (bought custom parts and assembled them). He thought it was taking too long to install so he rebooted the computer (I tried telling him not to lol). Ever since he did that, I have had the same problem that the person who originally posted the question in the above link.

What should I do? And thank you for your time for reading this

*I tried sending this to a specific user, but if anyone knows what to do, I would appreciate it!*

Comment: Since the installation of Windows most likely failed and there is no critical data on the HD I would just re-install Windows.

Comment: The most valuable tool in troubleshooting and resolving any problem (technical or otherwise), is common sense. Your friend very likely interrupted the installation. Common sense would tell you to start the installation from scratch.

Comment: How do you reinstall windows and start from scratch? We've tried everything we could think of. Can you by any chance clear the space on the Hard Drive to start from scratch? And yes, common sense tells you my friend interrupted the installation lol, thats a given

Answer (score 1):

As the commentators have said, the installation is likely incomplete, as it was interrupted.

Put the Windows 7 disc back in and boot from it again, and (re)install Windows using the same process as you did last time. When given the choice between Typical/Standard/Custom install, select Custom. Among other things, this will give you the chance to delete the existing partitions so you can start from scratch.

Comment: When I put the disk back in, nothing happens. This is where my concern is. What next?

Comment: Press F12 upon boot to select the device to boot from (your CD drive).

Comment: I've done that. Western Digital told me to run an Diagnostics test and I did. If ANY error appears after the test, then I need a new hard drive. Surely enough I got an error lol. So I'm just gonna get another one, but thank you for the help BigBio2002!